# If statement skipping condition

Tags: c#, if-statement, error-handling, skip

I have some code, but the if condition is skipping and not being executed even though when it's true. My code in simple terms is as follows:

```
for(int i = 13;i<anarray.length;i++)
    if(i == 13)
    {
      for(w = i;w>12;w--)
      {
        if(anarray[w] > 0)     //the program skips this line completely even though the element is greater than 0
        { 
            //do some adding
        }
        if(anarray[w] < 0)
        {
            //do some other adding
        }
      }
    }
```

The following pictures should help:

Debug 1:
[image]

Debug 2:
[image]

Debug 3: 
[image]

Debug 4:
[image]

Comment: You need `==` like `if(i == 13)`, Although it is not the cause of your bug/error

Comment: @Habib ya, sorry about that. I was just in a hurry typing, but you're right that's not the bug in the code

Comment: Why do you think that it is skipped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is from

```
for(int w= m_RSISSteps - 1; w > m_RSISteps - 1; w--)
```

you just defined `w` to be equal to `m_RSISteps - 1` so the `<` check evaluates to `false` and the for loop never executes. Likely your check needs to be corrected, perhaps you meant to do `w >= 0` or use some other variable than `m_RSISteps`.

To turn it in to your "simplified example" it is like you did

```
for(int i = 12;i<anarray.length;i++) //These should be 12 not 13 based off of your images.
    if(i == 12)
    {
      for(w = 12;w>12;w--) //HERE
      {
        if(anarray[w] > 0)     //the program skips this line completely even though the element is greater than 0
        { 
            //do some adding
        }
        if(anarray[w] < 0)
        {
            //do some other adding
        }
      }
    }
```